# pgAdmin4 for web and HTTPS

Tags: pgadmin-4

I've installed pgAdmin4 in an Ubuntu instance using the following instructions https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-apt/.

Everything is installed and configured without any problems, but I when I try to go to the `Users` section, it doesn't do anything. In Chrome's DevTools I can see few requests that, apparently, are fine:

[Requests when select Users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8q62d.png)

The first request looks like this:

[first request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajr9a.png)

And the second looks like this:

[second request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xtvg7.png)

I've looked in the documentation and I didn't see anything regarding this. Could it be because it needs to be a secure request? Does it need to have a valid certificate?
What could be the reason for this not to work?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you insert screenshots of what you're encountering, instead of giving links? Regards.

Comment: Hi @MarcLeBihan, unfortunately I cannot do that because it's a new account and Stackoverflow doesn't allow to embed images until you reach a certain level.